# Is it possible to create a Wi-Fi hotspot from iPhone that's not ad-hoc?

Tags: iphone, wifi, network

First off, I am well aware of how to—in general—create a wireless hotspot using an ad-hoc network directly from my iPhone.

I have previously used the latest version of MyWi (version 4.12.6 at time of writing) but it creates ad-hoc networks and this doesn't work for me.

I *do not* want to and *cannot* create an ad-hoc network from my iPhone to allow another device to share its connection (must be wireless, as bridged connections don't help either).

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: You have to jail break your iPhone to enable it as a WiFi hotspot.

Comment: @tawman - as I said, I am well aware of how to create a wifi hotspot - my question is, is it possible to do so without creating an ad-hoc network

Comment: Not until iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 4.3 there will be Personal Hotspot integrated in firmware. Just wait

Comment: @JM4 the point is, since this will come in the next release nobody will bother developing such thing. And no, no solution exists to this date to do that - also because nobody had enough reasons to do it.

Comment: @JM4 just prove me wrong and bring a solution then.

Comment: @JM4: maybe try being a little less confrontational with people who are actually trying to help you out?